# Why can I suddenly no longer write to files in Python?

Tags: python, windows, file-writing

Whenever I try to write or modify the data of a file in any way I get this error everytime:

```
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Here's what I've been trying to do:

```py
# output.txt is the file already created inside of the same directory

with open(__file__.rsplit("\\", 1)[0] + "\\output.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("this should write to 'output.txt'")
```

I would try to dump with json or append with normal data but I'm continuously recieving the same error.

In the above example, here is the entire output of the terminal after execution:

```
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Programming\Code\Python\Testing>c:\Users\USER\Documents\Programming\Code\Python\Testing\z_3.py
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Programming\Code\Python\Testing\z_3.py", line 4, in <module>
    f.write("this should write to 'output.txt'")
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

This is all very strange because I've been able to write to files normally but I've just recently reinstalled windows and now it won't work.

Comment: Check the NTFS permissions of the user on whose behalf the script is executed.

Comment: @viilpe Where would these permissions be if I were to check?

Comment: just google "NTFS permissions". Make sure that the paths from your script actually exist.

Comment: @viilpe Nada, literally just gave everything "Full Control" which was an awful idea but it still gives me Bad File Descriptor".